# What should I name a class whose sole purpose is procedural?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, 3d, modeling

I have a lot to learn in the way of OO patterns and this is a problem I've come across over the years. I end up in situations where my classes' sole purpose is procedural, just basically wrapping a procedure up in a class. It doesn't seem like the right OO way to do things, and I wonder if someone is experienced with this problem enough to help me consider it in a different way. My specific example in the current application follows.

In my application I'm taking a set of points from engineering survey equipment and normalizing them to be used elsewhere in the program. By "normalize" I mean a set of transformations of the full data set until a destination orientation is reached.

Each transformation procedure will take the input of an array of points (i.e. of the form `class point { float x; float y; float z; }`) and return an array of the same length but with different values. For example, a transformation like `point[] RotateXY(point[] inList, float angle)`. The other kind of procedure wold be of the analysis type, used to supplement the normalization process and decide what transformation to do next. This type of procedure takes in the same points as a parameter but returns a different kind of dataset.

My question is, what is a good pattern to use in this situation? The one I was about to code in was a Normalization class which inherits class types of RotationXY for instance. But RotationXY's sole purpose is to rotate the points, so it would basically be implementing a single function. This doesn't seem very nice, though, for the reasons I mentioned in the first paragraph.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That doesn't really solve it -- let's assume it's a static class, in this case the Normalization is a static class that just has its procedures defined all over the place elsewhere in sub-namespaces. Maybe I'm just overthinking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common/natural approach for finding candidate classes in your problem domain is to [look for nouns](http://archive.eiffel.com/doc/manuals/technology/oosc/finding/page.html) and then scan for the verbs/actions associated with those nouns to find the behavior that each class should implement. While this is generally a good advise, it doesn't mean that your objects must only represent concrete elements. When processes (which are generally modeled as methods) start to grow and become complex, it is a good practice to model them as objects. So, if your transformation has a weight on its own, it is ok to model it as an object and do something like:

```
class RotateXY
{
public function apply(point p)
{
//Apply the transformation
}
}

t = new RotateXY();
newPoint = t->apply(oldPoint);
```

in case you have many transformations you can create a polymorphic hierarchy and even chain one transformation after another. If you want to dig a bit deeper you can also take a look at the [Command](http://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html) design pattern, which closely relates to this.

Some final comments:

- If it fits your case, it is a good idea to model the transformation at the point level and then apply it to a collection of points. In that way you can properly isolate the transformation concept and is also easier to write test cases. You can later even create a [Composite](http://www.oodesign.com/composite-pattern.html) of transformations if you need.
- I generally don't like the `Utils` (or similar) classes with a bunch of static methods, since in most of the cases it means that your model is missing the abstraction that should carry that behavior.

HTH

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. This addresses my discomfort with a hierarchy of static classes and offers some good ideas for naming and patterns to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when it comes to classes that contain only static methods, I name them Util, e.g. DbUtil for facading DB access, FileUtil for file I/O etc.  So find some term that all your methods have in common and name it that Util. Maybe in your case GeometryUtil or something along those lines.

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful to know the Util name is used often in such cases. I will start doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the particulars of the transformations you apply seem ad-hoc for the problem and possibly prone to change in the future you could code them in a configuration file.

The point's client would read from the file and know what to do. As for the rotation or any other transformation method, they could go well as part of the Point class.

Comment: Thanks, Jubbat. I will def implement the transformations as part of the point class, and had not considered doing a config file.

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing particularly wrong with classes/interfaces having just essentially one member.

In your case the member is an "Operation with some arguments of one type that returns same type" - common for some math/functional problems. You may find convenient to have interface/base class and helper methods that combine multiple transformation classes together into more complex transformation.

Alternative approach: if you language support it is just go functional style altogether (similar to LINQ in C#).

On functional style suggestion: I's start with following basic functions (probably just find them in standard libraries for the language)

- `collection = map(collection, perItemFunction)` to transform all items in a collection (`Select` in C#)
- `item = reduce (collection, agregateFunction)` to reduce all items into single entity (`Aggregate` in C#)
- combine 2 functions on item `funcOnItem = combine(funcFirst, funcSecond)`. Can be expressed as lambda in C# `Func<T,T> combined = x => second(first(x))`.
- "bind"/[curry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) - fix one of arguments of a function `functionOfOneArg = curry(funcOfArgs, fixedFirstArg)`. Can be expressed in C# as lambda `Func<T,T> curried = x => funcOfTwoArg(fixedFirstArg, x)`.

This list will let you do something like "turn all points in collection on a over X axis by 10 and shift Y by 15": `map(points, combine(curry(rotateX, 10), curry(shiftY(15)))`.

The syntax will depend on language. I.e. in JavaScript you just pass functions (and map/reduce are part of language already), C# - lambda and `Func` classes (like on argument function - `Func<T,R>`) are an option. In some languages you have to explicitly use class/interface to represent a "function" object.

Alternative approach: If you actually dealing with points and transformation another traditional approach is to use Matrix to represent all linear operations (if your language supports custom operators you get very natural looking code).

Comment: Alexei: I really like the idea of going functional style as with LINQ. Can you give an example of how I might do that here? I thought the only way to define a Linq expression was inline as a member of a class.